# Why did Remy Bressant attack the bar in Gone Baby Gone

Tags: plot-explanation, gone-baby-gone

Remy Bressant attacks the bar where he ends up getting shot. It is later revealed that he was in fact working to save the girl and tried to hide it from Patrick. But I am not able to understand why he took a gun to the bar in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remy knew that Lionel will reveal the details about the kidnapping to Patrick. He couldn't allow this to happen, so he staged the robbery to kill Lionel (or both) and hide the truth.